# Is it possible to get the number of rows from a table in O(1) time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL server, obviously one way of getting the number of rows in a table is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable
```

but I assume that's `O(n)` time where `n` is the number of rows. Is there any metadata I can access that has the number of rows stored?

Comment: I'm sure there are Stack Overflow answers, but this shows you how:  http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/database/6576-sql-server-quickly-get-row-counts-for-tables-heaps-indexes-and-partitions.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `sys.partitions`, it might not be the exact number, but it's extremely fast:

```
SELECT SUM(rows) 
FROM sys.partitions
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable')
AND index_id IN (0,1);
```